# Worldmap doesn't display Data from the .CSV File

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to do python crash course exercise 16-7, I wrote this program, I got the different countries plotted on the map, but the expense data only came out the last country's value, I spent a few days trying to work on this problem, but it didn't seem working. What did I do wrong? please help, I'm greatly appreciated! Thank you very much!

**expenses.py**

```
import csv

from pygal.maps.world import World

from pygal.style import LightColorizedStyle as LCS, RotateStyle as RS

from country_codes import get_country_code

#load the data into a list.
filename = 'expense.csv'
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)
    header_row = next(reader)
    header_row = next(reader)
    header_row = next(reader)
    header_row = next(reader)

    cc_expenses = {}
    country_names, expenses = [], []
    for row in reader:
        country_name = row[0]
        expense = row[61]
        country_names.append(country_name)
        expenses.append(expense)
        code = get_country_code(country_name)
        if code:
            cc_expenses[code]= expense
# Everything work up to this point.

# Group the countries into 3 population levels.
cc_es_1, cc_es_2, cc_es_3 = {}, {}, {}
for cc, e in cc_expenses.items():

    e = int(float(expense))

    if e < 20:
        cc_es_1[cc] = e
    elif e < 40:
        cc_es_2[cc] = e
    else:
        cc_es_3[cc] = e

# See how many countries are in each level.
print(len(cc_es_1), len(cc_es_2), len(cc_es_3))

wm_style = RS('#336699', base_style=LCS)  

wm = World(style=wm_style)
wm.title = 'World Expense(% of GDP) in 2017, by Country'
wm.add('0-20', cc_es_1)
wm.add('20-40', cc_es_2)
wm.add('>40', cc_es_3)

wm.render_to_file('world_expenses.svg')


**countries.py**

from pygal.maps.world import COUNTRIES

for country_code in sorted(COUNTRIES.keys()):
    print(country_code, COUNTRIES[country_code])


**country_codes.py**
from pygal.maps.world import COUNTRIES

from pygal.maps.world import World

def get_country_code(country_name):
    '''Return the Pygal 2-digit country code for the given country.'''
    for code, name in COUNTRIES.items():
        if name == country_name:
            return code
    # If the country wasn't found, return None.
    return None
```

**expense.csv**
https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/GC.XPN.TOTL.GD.ZS?view=chart

I download the csv file as book says

Comment: The issue is in your loop that goes through the items in the cc_expenses dictionary. cc holds the country code, and e holds the expense. But then you say 'e = int(float(expense))'. expense was last defined as row[61], so it's whatever was in the last row in the loop that looked through the data file. I think you meant to use 'e = int(float(e)'?

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment, I think that's where it went wrong too, but I tried to change to e=int(float(e)), it came out: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "expenses.py", line 41, in <module>
    e = int(float(e))
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: What's the value that it's trying to convert when you get that error? One of the most common issues in data visualization is dealing with inconsistently formatted data. You can put a line right before that line: print('e:', e). The last value printed before the error will be the one it's failing on. Some IDEs make these values available without having to write your own print() call. Once you know the problematic value, you can sort out a solution to avoid that error.

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint! I printed out 'e:,e' as you suggested, found out its some data missing in the csv file, then I wrote a if len(e) > 0:  I got it after all!